# What happens if you kill a long-running alter query?

Tags: mysql, kill, alter

What happens if you kill a long-running alter query? Will the alter query simply revert? How long could that take (as a proportion of the time it has already been running)?

What if that query is being replicated onto another server? Will killing the process on the other server revert the original server's alter query?

We're running mysql

Comment: Haha, I'm sorry, I have a hilarious mental image of a bunch of engineers huddling around a monitor, peering through their sweaty brows at this post - just waiting for an answer - while a mysql server in the background begins to smoke.

Comment: haha, we pretty much had to let it smoke until the query finished. But it'd be nice to know for next time.. god forbid

Comment: Well, here I am. I was in the case were a copy was made, so stopping it was fine, but there was sweating involved. Thank god it wasn't in production but the write-lock is infamous.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It depends what you're doing. If you're running `an alter table...add index` command on an `InnoDB` table (not so sure about `MyISAM`), then it will just run and run as it copies the whole darn table lock-stock-and-barrel first: if it's in the middle of "copy to temp table" then it's pretty much unstoppable.

[See here:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)

> In most cases, ALTER TABLE works by
>   making a temporary copy of the
>   original table. The alteration is
>   performed on the copy, and then the
>   original table is deleted and the new
>   one is renamed. While ALTER TABLE is
>   executing, the original table is
>   readable by other sessions. Updates
>   and writes to the table are stalled
>   until the new table is ready, and then
>   are automatically redirected to the
>   new table without any failed updates.

Comment: It looks like our case was one where "no temporary table is necessary" - but it looks like our tables still locked up, our open connections spiked, and we had a 5 to 10 minute outage. If we kill a query that does *not* create a copy... then what?

Comment: @BT: How come no temporary table were created, what's your specific case?

Comment: BTW, I killed the process during the copy to temp table, it removed the write-lock and the data was still there and accessible. I have no idea where the temp copy went.

Comment: The temp copy is unlinked when the ALTER is interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

> What if that query is being replicated onto another server?

The ALTER will be executed on that server as well, with the associated impacts.

> Will killing the process on the other server revert the original server's alter query?

Nope. The original server has no back channel to learn about what occurred (or didn't) on the slave. If you kill the ALTER on the slave, then you will wind up in the situation where the master has the new constraint or index, and the slave doesn't. This is rarely a recipe for happiness :)

Once an ALTER enters the replication log, you either have to let it run everywhere, or kill it everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Start by executing the command:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

Next, carefully examine the process list and look for any entries with the status `copying to temp table.` If you identify queries with this status, it indicates that they are less risky to terminate. In such cases, you can safely terminate the query by executing the following command:

```
KILL QUERY_ID;
```

Replace 'QUERY_ID' with the actual ID of the query you wish to terminate. You can find the query's ID in the list displayed by the `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` command.

When you kill a query in MySQL using the KILL QUERY command, it instructs MySQL to stop the execution of the specified query.

This usually results in a change of the query's state from "copying to temp table" or another state to "killed" in the SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST.

Additionally, MySQL initiates a rollback process to undo any changes made by the query. The impact of the rollback may vary depending on the query's progress. Killing a query can free up server resources, resolve deadlocks, and improve the performance of other queries on the server.

However, it's essential to use this command judiciously, as it can disrupt ongoing operations and potentially affect data consistency.

Comment: Please share more details. As far as I see, you haven't mention what happens when killing the query